# Show a Particular Page in Drupal 7 Table Pager

Tags: 7, forms, theming, paging

I have a table and a table pager in my form.

```
// $table_rows is an array containing data.
$page = 2; 
//$page indicates that I want to display the second page in the table pager 
//$page is dynamic. It depends on the user.
$per_page = 5; //No. of items per page    
$chunks = array_chunk($table_rows, $per_page, TRUE); // Split an array into chunks of $per_page

$html =  theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $chunks[$page], 'sticky' => TRUE)) . theme("pager", array('quantity',count($table_rows)));
```

The result of my code is below:

[image]

It works fine as expected , but my pager number is not. It must  show `2` as the current page. Where am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to show 2 page as default? is there a database query to fetch table rows?

Comment: @arpitr No, $page is dynamic , $table_rows is an array not from the database. :)

Comment: Does the pager load new content if you click on next?

Answer (score 1):

I think theme_pager in your case never know about current page, by which it can decide where to add 'page-current' class.

Try passing 'element' parameter the way you are doing for quantity.

```
$html =  theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $chunks[$page], 'sticky' => TRUE)) . theme("pager", array('element'=> $page, 'quantity',count($table_rows)));
```

While $page will be less than a value of actual current page value. Please see [theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) to see how it works.

Comment: I tried your code but the pager dissapears everytime I click the pager link. What's wrong?

Comment: That means that theme("pager", array('element'=> $page, 'quantity',count($table_rows))) returns nothing. Why?

Answer (score 0):

check out this

```
<?php
$per_page = 10;
// Initialize the pager
$current_page = pager_default_initialize(count($rows), $per_page);
// Split your list into page sized chunks
$chunks = array_chunk($rows, $per_page, TRUE);
// Show the appropriate items from the list
$output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $chunks[$current_page]));
// Show the pager
$output .= theme('pager', array('quantity',count($rows)));
?>
```